# fwrite not working inside foreach

Tags: php, debugging

I'm getting a list of links using the following code:

```
$links=htmlspecialchars($_POST['links']);
$ids = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $links));
$ids=array_filter($ids);
```

When I run a simple foreach like this:

```
$csv=fopen("php://output", "w");
foreach ($ids as $url)
{
    $line='';
$line="test";
fwrite($csv, $line);
}

header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data.csv";');
fpassthru($csv); //Generate downloadabñe CSV
fclose($csv);
```

It doesn't work. However, when I construct the $ids manually like this:

```
$ids=array();
$ids[0]='example';
```

The code works. The code works locally but not on a new hosting we bought.

What can I do?

P.S: If you can suggest a hosting for PHP, that would be great. I'm getting a lot of errors with my current hosting provider.

P.S: For you who asked, here you go the full code. It writes the variable 'hline' on the CSV, but not the variable line:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
require('simple_html_dom.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL); //Error reporting

//Set up csv
$hline='Home Depot URL'.','.'Home Depot Reviews'.','.'Lowes URL'.','.'Best Seller Title'.','.'Sales In Past Two Weeks'.',';
$hline.='Top Seller ID'.','.'eBay Stars Reviews'.PHP_EOL;
$csv=fopen("php://output", "w"); 
fwrite($csv, $hline);

//Get variables from form
$links=htmlspecialchars($_POST['links']);
$ids = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $links));
$ids=array_filter($ids);

if (isset($_POST['snag'])) {
$snag=htmlspecialchars($_POST['snag']); 
}

if (isset($_POST['lowes'])) {
$lowes=htmlspecialchars($_POST['lowes']);
}

$markup0=htmlspecialchars($_POST['markup']);
$markup20=htmlspecialchars($_POST['markup2']);
$soldn=htmlspecialchars($_POST['sold']);

//Start not working foreach

foreach ($ids as $url)
{
    $line='';
$line="test";
fwrite($csv, $line);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Service recommendations are off topic for SO.

Comment: Try hosting with AWS. Also, put your both your `header('...')` lines above the foreach loop.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Your original code is working locally or the one you modified? Also what is the error you get with the new host

Comment: Why are you looping an array and writing a static "test" to the file? Edit your question with code that reflects what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Hey! Not error at all, the CSV triggers to download but it's blank.

The original script is not working so I'm testing a simplified version of it. I'll update the answer with the whole code so you can check it up.

Comment: The code I published is working locally, but not on my hosting .

Comment: CHanging header position didn't work :/